# Change row order in r, kable package labeling

Tags: r, row, kable

I'd like to change the row order so that the yes row is first and the no row is second. Is there any way i can do that? the code is below:

```
DATA5$Predict=predict(best.mod,newx=y2, type="class")
DATA5$armedornot2=ifelse(DATA5$armedornot!=1,"Yes","No")
DATA5$Predict=ifelse(DATA5$Predict <0.5, "No","Yes")
armedtable <- table(DATA5[,c("armedornot2","Predict")]) 
newtable<-cbind(armedtable,No=c(0,0))
```

Also, is there a way to add a side label to the following table? I would like it to say "Actual" on the side and "Predicted" at the top. Thanks!

```
newtable %>% kable() %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left") %>% add_header_above(c("This is the title"=3))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5xfH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bases on your table (that I called `df`), you can do:

```r
df[order(rownames(df), decreasing = TRUE),]

    Yes No
Yes 101  0
No  360  0
```

Regarding the addition of side labels, you can rename columns and rows by doing:

```r
rownames(df) <- paste0("Actual_",rownames(df))
colnames(df) <- paste0("Predicted_",colnames(df))
```

**Data**

```r
df = data.frame('Yes' = c(360,101),
                'No' = c(0,0))
rownames(df) = c('No', 'Yes')
```